# Modeling Optical Properties of Doped Crystals

Tags: optics, models

I am interested in modeling the optical properties of crystals doped with lanthanides to investigate their luminescent properties.

What would be the best way to pursue this?

EDIT (In response for a request of more details):
I am interested in modeling two things in particular:

1. I would like to know what type of defect the dopant acts as. E.g. Is is an interstitial or substitution defect?
2. I would like to know if the material will exhibit luminescence and, if possible, what the absorption and emission spectra will look like. If this is not directly possible, is there some way to use the results to interpret or predict these properties?

Either ab-initio or heuristic modeling, or a combination, would be fine. I'd like to leave the discussion as open as possible to source the best answers.

Comment: A few more details might help. What optical properties are you interested in? What is the motivation? Are you interested in modeling from "first principles" or would a heuristic macroscopic response model be sufficient? I know you may not be able to answer all of these questions but whatever information you do have will probably help others provide an answer.

Comment: The edits help a lot. Unfortunately, they put this question clearly outside my field of expertise. It does appear that points 1 and 2 would require fundamentally different approaches.  My guess is that you would need to know the defect type to be able to attempt to determine the optical reponse. Then you may be able to use a density function theory code (GAMESS or Octopus) to model the optical response of a particular configuration (maybe like http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1519).